# How to pass outside function to WP_REST_Request

Tags: page-template, rest-api

Learning with WP REST I'm unsure how to properly pass what is typically at the beginning of a PHP page form to `WP_REST_Response`.  For example:

At the beginning of `page-foobar.php` if I have:

```
// IP ADDRESS
function ipAddress() {
    if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) :
        $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else :
        $ip_address = "undefined";
    endif;
    return $ip_address;
}
/*
    Template Name: Foobar
*/
```

and need to use `$ip_address` in:

```
function foobar(\WP_REST_Request $request) {
    if ($ip_address == "undefined") :
        return new WP_Error( 'bad_ip', 'No IP found', array( 'status' => 404 ) );
    endif;
}
```

how would I go about doing that?  When I searched I ran across:

[Pass a Variable from one file to another in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383661/pass-a-variable-from-one-file-to-another-in-wordpress) but I dont think it would be a good idea to pass as a global.  [Further researching Passing variables between files in WordPress or PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253543/passing-variables-between-files-in-wordpress-or-php) but I've already called the template in functions.php.  How can I pass a function from the template to the function request if it's stored in a different file?

Comment: You might want to take a look into the [`wp_cache_set();`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cache_set) function.

Comment: Should you not define `ipAddress()` in `functions.php`? Page templates are not a good place to define things, they're for using things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be, to declare the function in `functions.php` and then call it whenever you need.

Since you are trying to use superglobals, you can access them anywhere. Move the code from your `page-foobar.php` to your theme's `functions.php`, and use this whenever you need to access it:

```
ipAddress();
```

So, in your REST function you can have:

```
function foobar(\WP_REST_Request $request) {
    $ip_address = ipAddress();
    if ($ip_address == "undefined") :
        return new WP_Error( 'bad_ip', 'No IP found', array( 'status' => 404 ) );
    endif;
}
```